How to resolve "file not found" error with GCP domain wide delegation
I am trying to implement some code that works with the Google Drive API using a service account, domain wide delegation, and nodejs. I cannot figure out why the following code fails to access the file specified, but I believe that it is a permissions issue although I am not exactly sure how to verify this.
Why does the following code return a "404 file not found" error if the file id is correct (it is a folder in google drive), the user is the owner and creator of the file on the domain, and the service account has been given domain wide delegation in the google admin console with the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' scope:
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const axios = require('axios');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
const USER_TO_IMPERSONATE = "mark@domain.org"

const FILE = "correct_file_id"

const doStuff = async (gc, id) => {
    try {
        console.log(await gc.getAccessToken());
        const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: gc })
        const folderMetadata = await drive.files.get({
            fileId: id,
            fields: 'id, name, mimeType',
        });
        console.log(folderMetadata)
        return folderMetadata
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Error response:', error.response.data);
        }
        console.error('Error message:', error.message);
        console.error('There was an error!');
        return null
    }
}

exports.logServiceAccount = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({scopes: SCOPES})
    const client = await auth.getClient()
    client.subject = USER_TO_IMPERSONATE
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId()
    const metadataUrl = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email'
    const response = await axios.get(metadataUrl, {
      headers: { 'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google' },
    })
    const email = response.data

    const f = await doStuff(client, FILE)

    res.send(`Authenticated as service account: ${email}, Project ID: ${projectId}, file res: ${f == null ? "issue" : f}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving service account details:', error)
    res.status(500).send('Error retrieving service account details')
  }
}

Edit
for some reason, I can only get it to work with the JWT method from the google auth library. Here is the code in case anyone was struggling like me:
const auth = new google.auth.JWT({
            keyFile: KEY_FILE,
            scopes: SCOPES,
            subject: salesFolders[salesRepName]["email"]
        });
const driveClient = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth })


In google drive, did you add the service account in SHARE?

No, my understanding was that since I am impersonating the user who is the creator, I don't need to

@danyL - Adding the service account email address to the share is not necessary for DWD. However, that is another solution that I prefer as DWD has too much power.

Using a JWT is fine. When a Google Access Token is created by the libraries, a Signed JWT is the first step. This method is called "Assertion", "JWT Assertion" or "Signed Assertion" depending on the author and age of the documentation. More and more Google services are accepting assertions in addition to access tokens.

It appears that your code is using the service account attached to the service. Have you configured that service account for Domain Wide Delegation? You are also missing the next step to use the delegated identity (the user your code is impersonating). The answer by DazWilken is another good solution but you must make the service account key material (JSON) available to your application.

Use the Metadata Service when you've no alternative. In this case, you can create an authenticated client (with the domain-wide delegated Service Account) that impersonates a Workspace user (SUBJECT) with google-auth-library.
One way to do this is:
KEY="/path/to/key.json" \
SUBJECT="mark@domain.org" \
ID="..." \
node index.js

index.js:
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

const KEY = process.env.KEY;          // path/to/key.json
const SUBJECT = process.env.SUBJECT;  // mark@domain.org
const ID = process.env.ID

const main = async (id) => {
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
                clientOptions: {
                        subject: SUBJECT
                },
                keyFilename: KEY,
                scopes: SCOPES
        });
        const drive = google.drive({
                version: 'v3',
                auth: auth
        });
        const folderMetadata = await drive.files.get({
            fileId: id,
            fields: 'id, name, mimeType',
        });
        console.log(folderMetadata)
        return folderMetadata
}

main(ID);

You can validate the Drive File (ID) using APIs Explorer's Google Drive v3 files.get:
